# Rails Perform Tasks Async In Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tasks that I need to perform when a route in my `Controller` is called. Right now my code looks something like this (abbreviated):

```
 def set_quotas

    TaskOne.new().ex
    TaskTwo.new().ex
    TaskThree.new().ex
    
    quotas = @user.quotas
    render json: quotas, status: 200, each_serializer: Api::V1::QuotaSerializer
  end
```

Each task runs in order. However, several of them call to outside services. So the total time it takes to complete this call ends up being 4-8 seconds and we really want to speed that up.

What I'd like to do is run all three tasks in tandem, but wait until each is complete before I render the `json` response. What's the best way to accomplish this in Rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [threads](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html) for this.

Here's a simple solution:

```
def set_quotas
  [
    Thread.new { TaskOne.new().ex },
    Thread.new { TaskTwo.new().ex },
    Thread.new { TaskThree.new().ex }
  ].each &:join

  quotas = @user.quotas
  render json: quotas, status: 200, each_serializer: Api::V1::QuotaSerializer
end
```

However there are a couple of things to be aware of when using concurrency in Ruby. First and most importantly, when you use threads you will be subject to all the complications that come with concurrency. Expect headaches. Concurrency can confound simple tasks very quickly. For example, for your problem, you need to make sure that your three tasks are **truly independent**. Does one task rely on the output of another? Does one have a side-effect? Say, does one write some data to a db that a subsequent job depends on? If this is the case, then the above won't work and you'll need to figure out how to accommodate their specific interdependencies.

Second, ruby threads are [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads). (Assuming you are using MRI Ruby, and not Rubinius or JRuby.) This means that if you'll only get speedups with ruby threads for certain tasks. Luckily, web requests are one of the things that do *not* block ruby threads, meaning the above solution *will* make all the requests concurrently. You should see speedups with this solution.

Last, and this is somewhat specific to your use-case, when your app makes calls to third parties, it is generally a best practice to relegate that stuff to a worker. Calls to third parties are error prone, and it sucks to return 400s (500s, if you're not careful with error handling!) to the client. It's better to put that work into a queue and give the client a response that essentially says "Got the request, will do it later."

Given all this, if you find that you need something more powerful than native ruby threads, check out the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem.

@AbM's answer mentions Resque/DJ for this. For a more general solution, check out [ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). For some (but not all) variants, see the [ActiveJob adapter list](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html).