# Rails ActionCable - listen or subscribe to a background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have an action on my controller which queues jobs in Sidekiq. The queued job has a broadcast functionality, in hope that on the same request, I can wait for the background process to finish

```
# controller
def process
  results = []
  uniq_id_across = record id
  20.times do |i|
    channel_id = "micro-#{uniq_id_across}-#{i}"
    MicroServices::DoThisJob.perform_async(channel_id, {some: params_here})
    
    # I would like to subscribe to the channel
  end

  # wait for the bg jobs to finish before return
  render json: results
end
```

This is for background job

```
# MicroServices::DoThisJob
def perform(channel_id, params = {})
  results = {}
  sleep( 2 )
  ActionCable.server.broadcast( channel_id, {content: results})
end
```

Our goal is to do almost parallel processing without using THREAD which might lead to DB POOL issue. Users accessing the endpoint has no knowledge about PUB/SUB, all they know is normal API call, send and receive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951615/rails-perform-tasks-async-in-controller

Comment: Thank you AbM but trying to avoid THREADing.